# Sapper route problem (bug) - Rendering a persistent component

Tags: components, svelte, persistent, sapper, svelte-transition

The error consists in a repetitive component that is rendered on any route when some router link is clicked. This was not happening every time, and because of that is too important be careful with Svelte animations and Sapper routes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I don't know what would be the best format to share this.
I think, instead of describing the "solution" right in the question part, it's better to only describe the problem in the question part, and then create an answer with the "solution" yourself

Comment: Hi @WurmD. I really don't know how to use stackoverflow properly. So, thanks for your help and kindness.

Comment: Hi hi :) Better
Now to be even better, can you share here in the Question the full code that was leading to the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, i have been using transitions withou any other params like this:

```
<section transition:slide> ... </section>
```

This is not rendering any errors, but following the instructions of reddit seems like have other options to handler that and keep using additional parameters:

https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/e1xc0a/problem_with_routing_and_transitions/